# Trying to stop a service

Tags: powershell

I have 4 servers running a scheduled task that contains a restart-service command
3 of the servers restart the service
the other one fails with the cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot stop XXX service on computer

I have tested in powershell manually as administrator with executionpolicy unrestricted and that also fails.

I have search and searched for error and not yet found any advise as to what I need to do to fix.

The service is the same of all 4 servers and each of those 4 are configured the same.  The scheduled tasks are running locally on each server.

Any ideas on what I can do to understand what is going wrong, and what the issue may possibly be?

Comment: Post the PS script that you are using.

Comment: restart-service -name XXX

Comment: Did you try `Restart-Service -Name XXX -Force` ?

Comment: I have................